# double free() error after swapping rows of a matrix

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, matrix

I'm getting the double free or corruption error upon executing my code. Essentially, I am just creating a matrix in C (of any RxC dimension, which is why pointers are used), swapping two rows, printing the results, and then attempting to free the memory. When I do not swap the rows, the freeing works perfectly. When I do, it crashes. I've attempted to alter the way the swapping works to no avail. I think it has something to do with the temporary pointer for swapping going out of scope, but I'm not sure if this is the problem and how I would fix it.

MatElement is just a double.

```
typedef double MatElement;
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    MatElement** matrix = matrixAlloc(3,3);

    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }
    matrixPrint(matrix, "%5.1f", 3, 3);
    swapRows(matrix, 0, 2);
    matrixPrint(matrix, "%5.1f", 3, 3);

    matrixFree(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

The way the matrices are allocated:

```
MatElement **matrixAlloc(int nr, int nc) {
    int i;
    MatElement *ptr;
    MatElement **A;

    A = malloc(nr * sizeof(MatElement *)); /* array of ptrs   */
    ptr = calloc(nr * nc, sizeof(MatElement)); /* matrix elements */
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) /* set row pointers properly */
        A[i] = ptr + nc * i;
    return A;
}
```

The way they are freed:

```
void matrixFree(MatElement **A) {
    free(A[0]);
    free(A);
}
```

The way their rows are swapped:

```
void swapRows(MatElement** G, int pivotRow, int rowExamined) {
    MatElement* temp;

    temp = G[rowExamined];
    G[rowExamined] = G[pivotRow];
    G[pivotRow] = temp;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea about what would be causing this double free() / invalid free()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point, you are swapping the first row of the matrix into another position, so the `free(A[0])` in `matrixFree()` is attempting to free a pointer into the middle of the array, instead of the pointer returned by `calloc()`. You will need to save that original pointer somewhere so that you can pass it, unmolested, to `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix looks like this way :

A has all the pointers to the first element of all the rows. So initially, A[0] points to 0th row, A[1] to 1st row and so on.

So, when you are trying to free the matrix, you know that A[0] points to first row. But at that time you are assuming that your matrix elements are in continuous position and A[0] will always point to initial pointer returned by calloc. But when you swap some rows (specially the 0th with any of other row), then A[0] doesnt point to pointer returned by calloc.

possible solution involves like allocating one more memory slot in A like :

A = malloc( ((nr+1) * sizeof(MatElement *)); /* array of ptrs   */

and then storing original pointer returned by calloc to A[nr].

So, A[nr] will also point to calloc returned pointer.